# Export table to CSV from different .bak files iteratively

Tags: sql-server, export

I have a lot of different .bak files with the same structure (all of them have the same tables) and i would like to export a specific table inside of each of them in csv form.

I wonder if it is possible to do this in SQL iteratively.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ANSI SQL has no export functionality.)

Comment: Thanks jarlh for reply me, i am working with SQLOPS.

Comment: Unless your database is laid out with the table in question in a separate filegroup before you find yourself needing to restore, I don't think you can do this kind of thing.  This may be a long shot, but you may be able to parse out the table from all the .bak files, if you can convert each into an XML file and parse them using Python.  Just a thought.  See the link below for some ideas of how to get started.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html